# Execution context and the execution context object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

My head is spinning, can someone please explain how javascript stores variables and what is "Execution context" and "the execution context object"?

Why does the code snippet prints following output on console:

> the hello argument
>
> the hello argument

```js
var hello = 'hello is assigned';

function prison(hello) {
  console.log(hello);
  var hello;
  console.log(hello);
}
prison('the hello argument');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has less to do with execution context and everything to do with function variable scope. You're passing in `'the hello argument'` as an argument to the function and being local it is used instead of the `hello` var declared outside of the the function.

The `var hello` does nothing and if you were using `use strict` or a linter would probably raise a warning (trying to declare an existing variable).

If you changed it to `var hello = null;` you would see a change to the output.

Now, if you had the following code:

```
var hello = 'hello is assigned';

function prison() {
  console.log(hello);
  var hello;
  console.log(hello);
}

prison();
```

...you would get `undefined` for both logs. This would be due to [*variable hoisting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) - variable declarations are moved to the start of a function before execution - so the code would actually appear like so:

```
function prison() {
  var hello;
  console.log(hello);
  console.log(hello);
}
```

`hello` is `undefined` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

your function `prison()` has closure over variable `hello` , the `var hello;` in `prison()` is not creating a new variable , the function can see that there is already a global variable  `hello` defined so it uses that variable and hence you get 2 `the hello argument`

if however ,there was no `hello` defined before `prison()` you would get 2 `undefined`  bcoz the definition of `hello` would be hoisted in `prison()` and `hello` has no value set to it.